# How to add these inputs into a list so I can call them to display later in Python?

Tags: python, list, user-input

I'm trying to make a madlib game where I could store multiple stories and use a function or class to compile the user answers when selected or called. I want to be able to put multiple user inputs() into a list or dictionary so I could then call that list and display the questions

```
inputs = [name = input("\nI need a person's name: "), adjective_2 = input("An adjective: "), adverb_2 = input("Give me an adverb: ")]
```

but when I run it I get this error code:

```
File "/Volumes/Megabite/Dropbox/Coding/Jon/python_projects/chapter_9/inputs.py", line 1
inputs = [name = input("\nI need a person's name: "), adjective_2 = input("An adjective: "), adverb_2 = input("Give me an adverb: ")]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/Volumes/Megabite/Dropbox/Coding/Jon/python_projects/chapter_9/inputs.py']]
[dir: /Volumes/Megabite/Dropbox/Coding/Jon/python_projects/chapter_9]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I know I can declare the statements separately and then append it afterward but that usually causes the prompts to display right away. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you should use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can't set variables within a list declaration in Python. You have at least these 2 options:

1. If you don't care about naming the inputs and you're satisfied with e.g. just doing inputs[0] to get a person's name, you can use this:

```py
inputs = [input("\nI need a person's name: "), input("An adjective:"), input("Give me an adverb: ")]
```

2. If you want to give names to different elements of a list like structure, you can check out named tuples:

```py
import collections

# Create a namedtuple class named Inputs with names "name" "adjective_2" "adverb_2"
Inputs = collections.namedtuple("Inputs", ["name", "adjective_2", "advern_2"])   

# Set it
user_inputs = Inputs(name = input("\nI need a person's name: "), adjective_2 = input("An adjective: "), adverb_2 = input("Give me an adverb: "))
```